# postscript define string variable

Tags: postscript

I would like to make a variable called units that stores the string "cm". I have tried to do this in the following ways:

```
1) /units (cm) def
2) /units "cm" def
3) /units cm def
4) /units "cm" string def
```

here is a program that won't run:

```
/units (cm) def
0 0 moveto 100 100 lineto
```

none of which work, how can this be done?

To be more explicit, here is the program I want to create:

```
/units (cm) def
/Times-Roman findfont 20 scalefont setfont
300 300 moveto units show stroke
```

Comment: In what way does "/units (cm) def" not work ? That creates a string object and a name object and associates the string object "(cm)" with the key /units in the current dictionary. The second and third are valid PostScript but don't do what you  want, the fourth is invalid unless the object named "cm" is a numeric.

Comment: it doesn't work in the sense that it won't run, see the example I added

Comment: Again, won't run how ? If there's a problem then it should produce a PostScript error, if it does you should quote it. Just tried the example and it runs to cmpletion in Ghostscript

Comment: I can only open postscript files, I have no way of getting error messages

Comment: Open with what ? Can I suggest using Ghostscript ? You really need to use a proper PostScript interpreter if you want to debug PostScript programs. If you are expecting any output from that program you are going to be disappointed. You have not included a 'showpage' so any marking operations will not be transferred to the  output. In addition you have constructed a path, but done nothing with it. No stroke or fill operation is applied to the path. So you have not emitted any marking operations so the page is currently blank.

Comment: Your last example still lacks a showpage. Your stroke will be applied to an empty path (300 300 moveto) and so will do nohing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
/units (cm) def
/Times-Roman findfont 20 scalefont setfont
300 300 moveto units show
showpage
```

might be what you want